# Is it possible to combine the asterisk wildcard along with a couple more values in an INSERT INTO statement and if yes what is the right syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using a webpage that calls classic ASP pages written in VBscript that execute various tasks on a MS Access mdb.

On a particular task, that edits entries on a "production" table (let's call it tbl), I include an INSERT INTO, of the record that is about to be edited, to a backup table (let's call it tbl_bkp). So far this is quite simple:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_bkp
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE ID LIKE '" & ucase(request.querystring("theRecordId")) & "'
```

However the tbl_bkp appart from the same fields as tbl it has two additional fields to store a DateTime an IP of the user that edited the entry.

Is it possible to write a query to do the exact same job but also include the two additional variables in the same time?

Something like that:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_bkp
(SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE ID LIKE '" & ucase(request.querystring("theRecordId")) & "'),
dimDateTime,
dimUsersIP
```

Or probably like that:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_bkp
SELECT *,dimDateTime,dimUsersIP FROM tbl 
WHERE ID LIKE '" & ucase(request.querystring("theRecordId")) & "'
```

All I'm trying to do is avoid writing every field, because tbl and tbl_bkp have just so many fields.

**I admit both that this is probably NOT the best practice to keep a log of record changes and also that I could do the DateTime and IP insert on a second phase provided that I could get the id of the tbl_bkp row (since a record could be edited multiple times).**

Comment: Don't be lazy, specify the _columns_!

Comment: Nice answer! :D Actually to be honest I prefer spending some time to write a question in Stackoverflow than include every column in my query.

Comment: Most people here would say `select *` isn't considered good programming practice.

Comment: A lot of times us lazy folk just write a SQL statement to query the system tables that then generates a portion of the SELECT statement we are too lazy to write out by hand `SELECT "[" & Column_Name & "]," FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME="YOUR_TABLE_NAME" 
       AND 
    TABLE_SCHEMA="PUBLIC" ` for instance. Then we get a nice proper statement with out a `*` and without much work.

Comment: @JNevill I think OP is saying that they want to avoid writing out all the columns in the query in general, not that they can't be bothered. It's more of a "how can I use select * if I have extra values to select also?" question

Comment: JNevill I am not sure what you mean.
JohnHC I think you got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, providing the positioning is correct, you can do:

```
insert into t2
select t1.*, something, somethingelse
from MyTable t1
```

Perhaps this works in Access too?

Comment: Nice idea, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, both using MS Access directly and MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0 from the ASP page I get the same error respectively:   `No destination field name in insert into statement` AND
`Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14'
No destination field name in INSERT INTO statement ('192.168.1.100').` The IP is the first something table.

Comment: @Karapapas Looks like you're gonna have to type out the columns